# C# Two way dictionary ambiguity between two overloads of same kind

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to create a custom dictionary which accepts two data types and allows looks up in both directions (value to key and key to value).
If there are two different data types the class uses two different dictionaries (OnetoTwo and TwotoOne) while if there is only one data type it uses OnetoOne. Here is some of the code I have:

```
        public class TwoWayDictionary<T1, T2>
        {
            public Dictionary<T1, T2> OnetoTwo;
            public Dictionary<T2, T1> TwotoOne;
            public Dictionary<T1, T1> OnetoOne;

            public bool Same = false;
            public TwoWayDictionary()
            {
                if (typeof(T1) == typeof(T2))
                {
                    Same = true;
                    OnetoOne = new Dictionary<T1, T1>();
                }
                else
                {
                    OnetoTwo = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
                    TwotoOne = new Dictionary<T2, T1>();
                }
            }
            public T2 this[T1 key]
            {

                get => Get(key);
                set => Set(key, value);
            }
            public T1 this[T2 key]
            {

                get => Get(key);
                set => Set(value, key);
            }
            public void Add(T1 t1, T2 t2)
            {
                OnetoTwo.Add(t1, t2);
                TwotoOne.Add(t2, t1);
            }
            public void Add(T1 t1, T1 t2)
            {
                OnetoOne.Add(t1, t2);
                OnetoOne.Add(t2, t1);
            }
            public dynamic Get(object T_G)
            {
                if (Same)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return OnetoOne[(T1)T_G];
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return OnetoTwo[(T1)T_G];
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            return TwotoOne[(T2)T_G];
                        }
                        catch { return null; }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Set(T1 T1_S, T2 T2_S)
            {
               
                try
                {
                    if (!Same)
                    {
                        T1 Test = TwotoOne[T2_S];
                        OnetoTwo.Remove(Test);
                        OnetoTwo.Add(T1_S, T2_S);
                        TwotoOne[T2_S] = T1_S;
                    }
                }
                catch { }

            }
            public void Set(T1 T1_S, T1 T2_S)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Same)
                    {
                        T1 Test = OnetoOne[T1_S];
                        OnetoOne.Remove(Test);
                        OnetoOne.Add(T2_S, T1_S);
                        OnetoOne[T1_S] = T2_S;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
```

It works fine when I have 2 different data types for example when I have <int, string> I could do:

```
TwoWayDictionary<int, int> TestSame = new TwoWayDictionary<int, int>();
TwoWayDictionary<int, string> TestDiff = new TwoWayDictionary<int, string>();
TestDiff.Add(1, "SomeString"); // This is fine
Console.WriteLine(TestDiff[1]); // This is fine
TestSame.Add(1, 2); // This produces CS0121 (ambiguity)
Console.WriteLine(TestSame[2]); // This produces CS0121 (ambiguity)
```

However when I have two of the same data types for example <int, int> there is ambiguity between "T1" and "T2" which is understandable because they are both are integers.
What I want is when the program detects ambiguity for same data types to default to the methods which have parameters with the same type like `public void Add(T1 t1, T1 t2)`

Comment: You seem to have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How to resolve ambiguities is well-understood and the site has plenty of answers, which you can find if you search for them. Using the design you have above, you cannot avoid using those solutions. But your design seems flawed to me. You may get answers more useful to you if you explain why you need to handle identical type parameters as a special case in the first place. I'd also advise against using `dynamic` as a _return_ type. Please improve the question.

Comment: You should *really* not swallow exceptions the way that you are.  That's just a way of making bigger problems for yourself.  Additionally, your `Get` method is causing way more problems for yourself in your attempt to have a single method to handle both types.  It introduces tons of ways for it to fail at runtime that simply can't happen if you simply have two methods, one for each type.  The code will be simpler, way less error prone, faster, and way easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to just remove all of the code that you have internally do do different things when the types are the same.  Just store the data in two dictionaries, it'll work just fine, if not better than what you're trying to do.

If there is actually some compelling reason you have to have a single dictionary with twice as many items instead of two dictionaries when the types are the same (I don't see a reason for it, but if there is one...) then make a *separate type* that has a single generic argument rather than two and is implemented with a single internal dictionary, leaving the two-type version as described above, written to work with no special casing for the case where the types are the same.